# Filter by two conditions + Array Formula alternative in google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I am well aware that FILTER doesn't work with Array Formula. On all of the posts I've seen, people are substituting it by Array Formula + Vlookup. My problem is that I use FILTER on more than one condition.

Example: FILTER(Deliveries!A:A, Deliveries!C:C=A2,Deliveries!B:B=B2)) (This is in a different sheet, where I use filters in both Columns B and C).

This sheet is the repository of a form, and when the form adds rows the formulas do not get copied down to the added rows, hence my effort to turn this into an Array Formula or maybe a query. I'd be equally satisfied with another solution (i.e. something that forced  formulas to always follow the addition of new rows).

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try in row 1:

```
={"header"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, 
 {Deliveries!C:C&Deliveries!B:B, Deliveries!A:A}, 2, 0)))}
```

Comment: This formula is the definition of perfection. I can't tell you how much this will save me. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm using this formula on several cases and it works very well but for some reason when the search value and the result value is an importrange it results me an error saying my lookup is searching out of bounds. If I change the "2" at the end of the formula for a 1 it works but only returning the search value. Do you know a workaround?

Comment: @MarcusCatan did you run IMPORTRANGE as standalone formula prior to your attempt? sheets needs to be connected only then you can use MPORTRANGE in the formula.

Comment: I did, I made it work prior to the attempt on the vlookup. Are you usually able to do this formula with importranges normally?

Comment: @MarcusCatan should be doable. can you share a copy of your sheets?

Comment: I can't share the spreadsheets I use but I managed to reproduce the error explicitly in two test sheets: 
Sheet1 : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jL1ZrQYQ1_mFqmNcZg_7dXFD53GVb3pG-ahNx8kzhL8/edit#gid=0
Sheet 2:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QyOmkA50yIHLo7yk3RUNjVFeDHNOp4LaIYqyoI0UEA8/edit#gid=0

Comment: @MarcusCatan you used `Sheet1!G:G` instead of `Sheet1!C:C`. see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl6BN.png

Comment: Sorry for the dumb mistake. Thank you very much.